# Two Html buttons for two different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which has two Options, Submit and Overwrite.

It looks like this:

```
[ INPUT FIELD ]
[Submit] [Overwrite]
```

The Overwrite Button only appears when the value already is in the Database.

The HTML Code is:

```
<input type="text"  name="target" id="target">
<button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>
<button id="overwrite" name="overwrite" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Overwrite </button>
```

The JS Code is:

```
    if(!problem){
        data = "submit=save";

        jQuery('#overwrite').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');

        if( $(this).hasClass('selected') ){
         data+="&overwrite=on";
         console.log( "overwrite=on" ); 
        }
       });

        sendToBean(href, data);

        jQuery.each(langs, function(i, lang){
             sendToBean(href, data);
        });
    }
}
```

If I only have the Submit button, it works.
If I only have the Overwrite button, it works.
But if I have both, the Overwrite button wont work anymore.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

put `retrun false` in the anonymous callback function will do the trick. since you declare that the button is a submit button

```
if(!problem){
    data = "submit=save";

    jQuery('#overwrite').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    if( $(this).hasClass('selected') ){
     data+="&overwrite=on";
     console.log( "overwrite=on" ); 
    }
    return false;
   });

    sendToBean(href, data);

    jQuery.each(langs, function(i, lang){
         sendToBean(href, data);
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you click the submit button the page will be refreshed and the `overwrite` will return to the initial format and the selected will disappear, Try to change the input type to button :

```
<button id="overwrite" name="overwrite" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Overwrite </button>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<input type="">` for Overwrite button you may use `<button>`

```
<a href="#" id="overwrite" class="btn btn-primary"> Overwrite </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text"  name="target" id="target">
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnOverwrite" name="btnOverwrite" class="btn btn-primary" value="Overwrite"/>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnOverwrite").unbind("click").bind("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("overwrite called");    
  });
  $("#btnSubmit").unbind("click").bind("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("submit called");
  })
});
```

Review fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dipakchavda2912/rwdakvyg/